# How to disable recursive triggers in SQLite3?

Tags: sqlite

If I understand recursive triggers correctly, in case of these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE ids (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ON CONFLICT REPLACE
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE some_data (
    id   INTEGER REFERENCES ids (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
                                     ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    data TEXT
);
```

when the conflict in table ids appears, `REPLACE` should be performed, i.e. first deleting and then adding new value. This deleting should be cascaded only if `recursive trigger` is enabled, according to the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html):

> When the REPLACE conflict resolution strategy deletes rows in order to satisfy a constraint, delete triggers fire if and only if recursive triggers are enabled.

I understand that having the following code:

```
PRAGMA recursive_triggers = OFF;
PRAGMA recursive_triggers;
INSERT INTO ids (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO ids (id) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO some_data (id, data) VALUES (1, "addds");
UPDATE ids SET id = 1 WHERE id = 2;
```

data from table `some_data` shoudn't be removed, but are removed. What can I do to not recursively trigger `ON DELETE CASCADE` in this case?

My SQLite version is 3.35.4.

Comment: Its a little strange (the whole "replace" thing here). Probably since you still have a 1, maybe it is still a valid reference. That makes sense data-wise, even if its not what you expect.

Comment: Is there anything I can do in this use case to not removing data from `some_data` and still keeping `ON DELETE CASCADE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CASCADE action is not a trigger and thus not covered by recursive triggers; they are similar as per:- sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions

> What can I do to not recursively trigger ON DELETE CASCADE in this case?

Perhaps consider the following adaptation of your code where the update is preceded by a complimentary update.

The update effectively undertakes the CASCADE before the ensuing update (that then CASCADEs the implied delete to the children):-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS some_data;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ids;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ids (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ON CONFLICT REPLACE
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS some_data (
    id   INTEGER REFERENCES ids (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
                                     ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    data TEXT
);
INSERT INTO ids (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO ids (id) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO some_data (id, data) VALUES (1, 'addds');
UPDATE some_data SET id = 2 WHERE id = 1; /*<<<<<<<<<< ADDED UPDATE */
UPDATE ids SET id = 1 WHERE id = 2;
```